# Blank Screen Problem when trying to publish iOS App

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, release

We are encountering some issues with publishing our app.
First of all in debug mode it works on all emulators but during release, it doesn't work all the time.
We have encountered a blank screen problem on iPads. We encountered this problem on an iPhone as well (physical device), but after a `flutter clean` and `flutter build iOS -release` it worked.
Then we have archived the app without selecting "`compress the app`" in XCode.
Would you be able to tell us if you have experienced this "blank screen problem" on iPads ? We would really appreciate any pieces of advice. Thank you!

We use permission for notification and location.
We use the following packages in flutter pubspec:

```
- cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

- rxdart: ^0.18.0

- http: ^0.12.0+1

- firebase_database: ^2.0.2

- cloud_firestore: 0.9.13+1

- firebase_storage: ^2.1.0+1

- cached_network_image: ^0.7.0

- image_picker: ^0.5.3+1

- flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0

- flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.5.0

- firebase_auth: ^0.8.4+5

- url_launcher: ^5.0.2

- geolocator: ^4.0.1

- permission_handler: ^2.2.0

- shared_preferences: ^0.5.2

- flutter_range_slider: "^1.0.1"

- intl: ^0.15.8

- geocoder: ^0.1.2

- fluttertoast: ^3.0.4

- datetime_picker_formfield: ^0.1.8

- flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.0

- firebase_messaging: ^2.0.0

- firebase_crashlytics: ^0.0.4+2
```

```
if (geolocationStatus == GeolocationStatus.unknown)
      Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions =
          await PermissionHandler()
              .requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.location,PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]);
```

```
void iOS_Permission() {
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true)
    );
    firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, exact! similar problem with channel dev

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
redux: ^3.0.0
flutter_redux: ^0.5.3
firebase_auth: ^0.8.4+5
cloud_firestore: ^0.10.1
cloud_functions: ^0.2.0
firebase_storage: ^2.1.1+1
firebase_core: ^0.3.4
firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+4
firebase_analytics: 2.1.1+3
flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0
cached_network_image: ^0.7.0
shared_preferences: ^0.5.2
font_awesome_flutter: ^8.4.0
image_picker: ^0.6.0+2
image_cropper: ^1.0.1
connectivity: ^0.4.3+1
flutter_spinkit: ^3.1.0
event_bus: ^1.1.0
flutter_app_badger: ^1.0.2
flutter_image_compress: ^0.4.0
package_info: ^0.4.0+3
device_info: ^0.4.0+1
flutter_html: ^0.9.6
path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
flutter_cache_manager: ^0.3.2
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+3
timeago: ^2.0.14
google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.11+1
flutter_advanced_networkimage: ^0.4.15
location: ^2.3.5
intl: ^0.15.8
flutter_range_slider: "^1.2.0"
flutter_money_formatter: ^0.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
You need to add in Info.plist this:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>gps</string>
        <string>location-services</string>
    </array>
```